# Typographic mark (komejirushi) used in Chinese/Japanese/Korean

Tags: symbols, amssymb

I was looking for this symbol `※` ([more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_mark)). The closest I found is `\divideontimes` from `\usepackage{amssymb}`, but it replaces the horizontal dots by a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\divideontimes$
\end{document}
```

[image: divide-on-times]

I can probably go on the hard route to draw this in Tikz, but any simpler solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply use LuaLaTeX or XeTeX together with a font that has the glyph? The Unicode codepoint is U+203B REFERENCE MARK.

Comment: In addition to what Ingmar wrote, xits has the glyph.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My XITS has it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this compiles and produces the requested symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textreferencemark

\end{document}
```

[image]